# Is there referrer header while using SSL?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, referrer

Is there referrer header within domain while using SSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a
>   link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the
>   referrer field is not sent.
>
> The upcoming standard HTML5 will support the attribute/value rel =
>   "noreferrer" in order to instruct the user agent not to send a
>   referrer.

*Source:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

So it seems **referrer** is not within the domain, but within SSL.

Answer (score 3):

At least Chrome supports now a Meta Tag which explicitly allows to send the Referrer when going from HTTPS to HTTP. Just include the following line in the header:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Here is more Information:
http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Meta_referrer