# how can i get search word when a visitor comes from google search to my site?

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to customize my index.php when a visitor searchs for a word in google search and comes to my site.
ex:

```
if(visitor searches for "A" in google search)
   do somthing;
elseif(visitor searches for "B" in google search)
   do somthing else;
```

if i should use referrer tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this script:

```
function getKeywords()
{
    $refer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $host = $refer['host'];
    $refer = $refer['query'];

    if(strstr($host,'google'))
    {
        $match = preg_match('/&q=([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)/',$refer, $output);
        $querystring = $output[0];
        $querystring = str_replace('&q=','',$querystring);
        $keywords = explode('+',$querystring);
        return $keywords;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: this does not work when the someone used encrypted Google (which uses SSL): https://encrypted.google.com/

Comment: thank you that's grate function. but if i want to get this when someone used google.com with https what should i do?

Comment: There's no way, sorry. Read more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620328/is-there-referrer-header-while-using-ssl

Comment: Quote from Wikipedia: `If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the referrer field is not sent.`

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 this is no more possible. You will only get the referrer domain and no query stings.