# Request Referrer Not coming in case of Tumblr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tumblr

Request.referer is coming in all the other social media like facebook,twitter,linkedin but in case of Tumblr it's coming nil. So how can we know that from tumblr the request is coming from. I am creating the page where we are storing the view counts from different social media. For other social media everything is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the links coming from tumblr are not https? That could prevent the referrer from being sent as explained here: [Is there referrer header while using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620328/is-there-referrer-header-while-using-ssl)