# Concrete5 http_referrer not visible in $_SERVER array

Tags: concrete5

Using Concrete5 we cannot get the SERVER array to show the referrer.
eg: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] -> returns null.

It is a site on SSL.

We just need to get the last referring link if available.
We can use either PHP or Javascript, as long as we get the data we need.
What are we doing wrong?

Thanks in advance..

JD

Answer (score 0):

```
If a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to  
anywhere except another secure location, then the referrer field is not sent.

The upcoming standard HTML5 will support the attribute/value rel = "noreferrer" in order
to instruct the user agent not to send a referrer.
```

Source: [Is there referrer header while using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620328/is-there-referrer-header-while-using-ssl)

I doubt javascripts 'document.referrer' will work (since both php en javascript look at the same piece of information in the header)